# Check to see if an internal web site is up and running

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

Afternoon All,

I need to create a web page that essentially list my companies internal web sites.  I essentially need to check a status screen that displays if the web app is up and running or if it has failed.  I also need to do the same for the database instance it is associated with.

Im looking for some inforamtion to help me wirte some VB code in my ASP.net 2010 site that will complete this check for each web site for me.

Im not 100% sure on how to complete this task but thought i would be able to Ping the application name or th web box that this is located on?

I have been looking at the following [site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_internet_website.php) and code sample for some inspiration but i seem to be no further forward.

Would it be possible for someone to please advise the best way forward and to suggest something that may help me further?

Many thanks in advance.
Betty

Answer (score 0):

I see you used the technology. Net microsoft. And I think your sites and applications are hosted with "IIS"?

You should be able to use the class "**DirectoryEntry**" and its multiple properties.
You can like this, check the status of a website or a web application hosted on "ISS" and check the status of application pool.

Namespace to use : `System.DirectoryServices` (Available on **C#** & **ASP**)

More information about "DirectoryEntry" and them properties: [DirectoryEntry Info](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2746874d-062a-4153-83a2-2fc07242ce9c.mspx?mfr=true)

Something like this:

```
//Get the webSite ID
public static int GetWebsiteID(string websiteName)
{
     string machineName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
     DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://"+machineName+"/w3svc");
     int id = 1;
     foreach(DirectoryEntry de in w3svc.Children)
     {
          if(de.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer" && de.Properties["ServerComment"][0].ToString() == websiteName)
           {
                id = int.Parse(de.Name);
           }

     }
     return id;
}

//Check statut of webSite
public void checkStatutWebSite()
{
     DirectoryEntry myWebSite = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://" + machineName + "/w3svc/{0}/Root", GetWebsiteID("webSiteName")));
     ServerState state = (ServerState)Enum.Parse(typeof(ServerState), myWebSite.Properties["ServerState"].Value.ToString())
     if (state == ServerState.Stopped || state == ServerState.Paused)
     {
         //site is stopped
     }

}

public enum ServerState
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Starting = 1,
    Started = 2,
    Stopping = 3,
    Stopped = 4,
    Pausing = 5,
    Paused = 6,
    Continuing = 7
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: many thanks for the above.  Yes we use IIS and will take a look at System.DirectoryServices and see if i can make the above happen in VB.